# LoggingMiddleware NestJS: Duplicated log records

Tags: logging, nestjs, middleware

I was trying to create a LoggerMiddleware using NestMiddleware. I have created it using the approach from NestJS Documentation. I share the class below:

```
import { Injectable, NestMiddleware } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from 'express';
import { getReasonPhrase, StatusCodes } from 'http-status-codes';
import { AppLogger } from '../app-logger';
import { CommonLoggingHttpFunctions } from '../http/common-logging-http-functions';
import { HeadersInfoTreatment } from '../http/headers-info-treatment';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    constructor(private logger: AppLogger) {}

    public use(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
        this.logHttpRequest(request);
        response.on('close', () => {
            const httpStatusCode = response.statusCode ?? StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

            if (httpStatusCode < StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST) {
                this.logHttpResponse(response);
            } else {
                this.logHttpErrorResponse(response);
            }
        });

        next();
    }

    private logHttpRequest(request: Request): void {
        const httpVerb = request.method.toUpperCase();
        this.logger.log(`${httpVerb} ${request.url}`, {
            'http-msg': {
                headers: HeadersInfoTreatment.maskSensitiveInfo(request.headers),
                method: httpVerb,
                body: request.body
            },
        });
    }

    private logHttpResponse(response: Response): void {
        const httpVerb = response.req.method?.toUpperCase();
        const statusCode = response.statusCode ?? StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        const reasonPhrase = CommonLoggingHttpFunctions.isHttpStatusCode(response.statusCode)
            ? getReasonPhrase(response.statusCode)
            : '';
        this.logger.log(`${response.statusCode} ${reasonPhrase} ${httpVerb} ${response.req.url}`, {
            'http-msg': {
                headers: HeadersInfoTreatment.maskSensitiveInfo(response.getHeaders()),
                method: httpVerb,
                body: response,
                statusCode
            },
        });
    }

    private logHttpErrorResponse(response: Response): void {
        const httpVerb = response.req.method?.toUpperCase();
        const statusCode = response.statusCode ?? StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        const reasonPhrase = CommonLoggingHttpFunctions.isHttpStatusCode(statusCode)
            ? getReasonPhrase(statusCode)
            : '';

        this.logger.error(`${statusCode} ${reasonPhrase} ${httpVerb} ${response.req.url}`, {
            'http-msg': {
                headers: HeadersInfoTreatment.maskSensitiveInfo(response.getHeaders()),
                method: httpVerb,
                body: response,
                statusCode
            },
        });
    }
}
```

And my logging module:

```
import { DynamicModule, Global, MiddlewareConsumer, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';
import { CommonLoggingHttpFunctions, configureLogger, LoggingInterceptor } from '..';
import { AppLogger } from './app-logger';
import { CONFIG_OPTIONS, LoggingOptions } from './model';
import { LoggingMiddleware } from './middleware/logging.middleware';

@Global()
@Module({})
export class LoggingModule {
    public static register(options: LoggingOptions): DynamicModule {
        configureLogger(options);
        return {
            module: LoggingModule,
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: CONFIG_OPTIONS,
                    useValue: { logPayloads: true, ...options },
                },
                AppLogger,
                {
                    provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
                    useClass: LoggingInterceptor,
                },
            ],
            exports: [AppLogger],
        };
    }

    public configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
        consumer.apply(LoggingMiddleware).exclude(`(.*)${CommonLoggingHttpFunctions.excludeEndpoint}(.*)`).forRoutes('*');
    }
}
```

I have tried to remove the configure() function from logging module but then the app doesn't log anything and if I set it then the app writes it twice.

[image: Duplicated records]

It's happening the same for the responses. I have checked again the app module and it seems to be set in the right way too:

[image]

No duplicated imports, so what could be happening? How can I fix the duplicated records in this case?

Thanks in advance for the help :-D!

Comment: Do you have two `LoggingModule.register()` imports in your application?

Comment: No, I have just one